# Reduce installation time and increase the installation speed using drush command "site-install"

Tags: drush

Can anyone tell me how to increase the installation speed and reduce installation time using drush command "site-install".

or

Is there any alternate way to install the distribution via drush with minimal time.

Because, I am trying to install the larger size distribution via drush using "site-install" command. It takes more time to complete the installation and even some of the distributions are broken during installation after 10min time.

Is there any min requirement in-terms of hardware to install the distribution via drush. Or does it require any additional configuration in php.ini or httpd.conf config file.

We already tried to changing the config in php.ini file for the following attributes.

max_execution_time
memory_limit
max_input_time

Regards
Arun

Comment: Related: [Why is Drupal 7 so slow](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow).

Comment: I haven't taken any benchmarks, but an SSD seems to help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any min requirement in-terms of hardware to install the distribution via drush

No, there aren't any minimum hardware requirements. If your machine can run the software that Drush relies on, Drush can run.

> does it require any additional configuration in php.ini or httpd.conf config file

It depends on your environment - the [project page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) has all the information you'll need.

> Is there any alternate way to install the distribution via drush with minimal time

I don't see how there would be. The Drush guys aren't going to have made that process intentionally slow, so it'll probably be as quick as it can be.

> Can anyone tell me how to increase the installation speed and reduce installation time using drush command "site-install"

That's down to the specs of your machine; the obvious (if slightly patronising) answer is simply to buy better hardware if yours isn't up to the task you want to use it for.

Bottom line, if you're installing a "larger size distribution" you can expect it take more resources. If that amount of resources is more than you have to give, it's time to look at buying better hardware.